# How to use "um ... zu" with separable verbs?

Tags: separable-verb

I know the purpose of using "um ... zu" in a sentence, but the problem arises when there is a separable verb. For example: um an zu ziehen or um zu anziehen?

Comment: I tried to improve your question. To further increase the chance of survival of your post, I suggest to elaborate your question. Give more examples, native speakers can typically answer your questions much more better, but they need more explanation.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Answer (score 2):

*um an zu ziehen* or *um zu anziehen*?

Neither. It's

> Er brauchte noch Zeit, um sich an**zu**ziehen.

This follows the same scheme as the perfect participle of separable verbs:

> Er hat sich an**ge**zogen.

Comment: To be fair, the difference is just spelling.

Comment: As this is about separable verbs, separating its parts or not makes a great  difference.

Comment: @Janka: true, but you can't hear the difference, while you can clearly hear the difference between *um anzuziehen* and *um zu anziehen*.

Comment: @CarstenS It does, however, make a difference: "Um die Jacke anzuziehen" is different from "Um an der Jacke zu ziehen" ;-) The Verb is "anziehen", not "an ziehen".

Answer (score 2):

> Um fair zu sein, muss ich sagen, dass Deutsch manchmal sehr verwirrend ist.

This is fine.

> Er gab alles, um sein Ziel zu erreichen.

This also.

> Es gab nicht viel Zeit, um die Segel einzuholen.

This also. The "zu" is always right in front of your verb.

Rule of thumb: If your verb is two separate words in first person singular, the "zu" goes between these two words. E.g.

> Ich ziehe mich an. --> Ich brauche noch einen Moment, um mich anzuziehen.